# How do I get the last uri segment from within a plugin (php)

Tags: plugin-development, url, validation

I have some validation that checks for a unique email when creating a new person. Works great.

When I am updating the person, it's no surprise the system won't let me save because the email I am saving already exists.

I am working on a condition that compares the id to the existing person to who is getting updated.

**Plugin_EmailValidator.php**

```
...
$person = craft()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('id, 'firstName, lastName')
    ->from('people')
    ->where('email=:email', array(':email' => $model['email']))
    ->queryRow();

if(!empty($person)) {
    error_log('MATCH FOUND');

   // I have the id of the existing account. Need to compare against uri segment?
  $existingId = $person['id];
  $segment = craft()->request->getLastSegment();

  error_log($segment); // error!

   $message = Craft::t("Email already exists.");
   $this->addError($model, $attribute, $message);
}
```

This is what my url looks like:

```
/admin/plugin/controller/update/123
```

I see examples of using the request methods within twig, i'm trying to access it via php.

I've also tried this:

```
craft()->request->getQuery('update');
```

This will run without error, but it also returns nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [segments](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService#segments-detail) property (shortcut for `getSegments()` method) of the HttpRequestServices class, which returns an array of uri segments.

```
craft()->request->segments;
```

To get the last segment you could use php's `end()` or `array_pop()` method.

```
$segments = craft()->request->segments;
echo end($segments);
```

Comment: So close, yet so far. Thank you - this worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad it worked! "So close, yet so far."?! The first of many challenges ahead? or what? :)

Comment: That - yes. :) And I was close to getting the above to work. On the right track anyway. Coming from CodeIgniter I knew what I was looking for, just not sure how to play by Craft's rules just yet.

Comment: Most of the time I don't know these answers off the top of my head either — but getting much better at finding answers. Most of this kind of functionality will be in the services class (so [requestServices](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService) in this case). Then look through the properties and methods until something catches your eye that looks like it might do the trick — or just `var_dump()` the object and go from there.